# NameError: Class not defined

Tags: python

Running the following code:

```
import math
    val=int(input("Vill du använda πr2(1) eller (πd2)/4(2)"))

if val == "1":
  class cirkel():
    def __init__(self,radie):
      self.A=radie
    def area(self):
      return ((self.A*self.A)*math.pi)

radie1=int(input("Vad är din radie?\n"))
circle=cirkel(radie1)
print("Arean av cirkeln är",circle.area())

if val == "2":
  class cirkel():
    def __init__(self,diameter):
      self.A=diameter
    def area(self):
      return  (((self.A*self.A)*math.pi)/4)

diameter1=int(input("vad är din diameter?\n"))
circle=cirkel(diameter1)
print("Arean av cirkeln är", circle.area())
```

results in this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 11, in
>      circle=cirkel(radie1) NameError: name 'cirkel' is not
> defined

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: `val` is an integer number. It is never equal to a string `"1"` or `"2"`.

Comment: Alright, but this
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    circle=cirkel(radie1)
NameError: name 'cirkel' is not defined`

Comment: It looks like you could benefit from a better IDE, linter and/or typehints.

Comment: There's one further piece of info missing from your question: what input did you give the program when you ran it when it resulted in this error. I can guess, but you should provide /all/ relevant info so that people can answer.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - the class in Python doesn't need parentheses, so `class cirkel():` should be turned into `class cirkel:`

Secondary - the main problem is in if condition - `if val == '1':` should be changed into `if val == 1:` because it is Integere comparison, not string.

Answer (score 0):

Your "val" has type int, but you're comparing it to string literals in the two if statements, meaning that the condition will never be true, resulting in "cirkel" being undefined.
You should either compare "val" with int literals (val == 1 instead of val == "1") or convert it to a string

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your code around a bit:

```
import math
val=int(input("Vill du använda πr2(1) eller (πd2)/4(2)"))

if val == "1":
  class cirkel():
    def __init__(self,radie):
      self.A=radie
    def area(self):
      return ((self.A*self.A)*math.pi)

  radie1=int(input("Vad är din radie?\n"))
  circle=cirkel(radie1)
  print("Arean av cirkeln är",circle.area())

if val == "2":
  class cirkel():
    def __init__(self,diameter):
      self.A=diameter
    def area(self):
      return  (((self.A*self.A)*math.pi)/4)

  diameter1=int(input("vad är din diameter?\n"))
  circle=cirkel(diameter1)
  print("Arean av cirkeln är", circle.area())
```

The reason is, in your code, if val is 2, the class `cirkel` isn't defined until after this bit:

```
radie1=int(input("Vad är din radie?\n"))
circle=cirkel(radie1)
print("Arean av cirkeln är",circle.area())
```

so when you attempt to set `circle=circle()` the class hasn't been defined yet.

I will say, overall this is not a good design. You should consider defining two separate classes and then decide which one to use based on the value of val, like:

```
class CircleRad:
    ...

class CircleDiam:
    ...

if val == 1:
    circle = CircleRad()
    ...
elif val == 2:
    circle = CircleDiam()
    ...
```

(Also note, classes should be named starting with a capital letter, by PEP8 conventions.)